# Does using select * in a subquery produces bad performance?

Tags: sql-server

I know the reason why using `select *` in the main query is bad. But what happens in a subquery?

1. Are all the columns retrieved from the table and then are selected just the ones listed in the outer select clause?
2. Is the query optimized and just the columns that are going to be selected afterward are retrieved from the table?

Real query example:

```
SELECT     T1.clave, 
           T1.titulo, 
           T1.revision, 
           T1.fecharevision, 
           T1.revisadopor, 
           T1. aprobadopor, 
           T1.nombrearchivo, 
           T1.descripcionarchivo, 
           T1.claverelacionada, 
           T1.archivo, 
           T1.link, 
           T1.fecharevlast, 
           T1.estatus 
    FROM   (SELECT *,
                   Row_number() 
                     OVER( 
                       partition BY revision 
                       ORDER BY fecharevlast DESC ) AS orden 
            FROM   motoresemis) AS T1 
    WHERE  T1.clave = 'CMD-01' AND T1.orden = 1
```

Answer (score 0):

For simple examples, it won't make a difference - SQL Server is a 'declarative' language which means the SQL command indicates what you *want*, not *how* to do it.

For example, I have a simple table called Test10k that has 10,000 rows, with ID a PK integer, then Col2, Col3, Col4, Col5 as varchar(100) filled with GUIDs. There's a non-clustered index on Col2.

The following commands all do exactly the same thing with same plans, cardinality estimates and IO statistics

```
SELECT  ID, rn
FROM    (SELECT ID, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY Col2) AS rn
        FROM Test10k
        WHERE Col2 LIKE 'F%'
        ) A;

SELECT  ID, rn
FROM    (SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY Col2) AS rn
        FROM Test10k
        WHERE Col2 LIKE 'F%'
        ) A;

SELECT  ID, rn
FROM    (SELECT ID, Col3, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY Col2) AS rn
        FROM Test10k
        WHERE Col2 LIKE 'F%'
        ) A;
```

- The first two compare the sub-query using the specific values desired vs *.
- The third one explicitly uses another column (Col3) that is *not* in the non-clustered index; SQL Server determines it's not needed so gets the data from the non-clustered index anyway.

The biggest problem SELECT * will do, is in complex setups (especially with grouping etc) it may not use an index even when logically it could, because your command is complex enough that SQL Server takes the parts as you say.

Also, when you are getting nearly the whole table in a sub-query, SELECT * or SELECT table.* will typically be better imo as it is much easier to read (as in your example above). If you are using nearly all the fields anyway, then it will need to use the clustered index to get the data anyway.

So, my suggestion

- Try to use explicit lists, just in case
- But when the list of columns from a given table becomes too long/more than a handful of columns, yeah use SELECT *  (but consider, if joining tables, using SELECT table.*)